# No module named 'dolfin' using Spyder

Tags: anaconda, ipython, spyder, fenics

I can't, for the life of me, get `dolfin`running with `Spyder`. That's what I thought at first. I managed to get it running somehow, but not in a convenient way. Here is the situation:

**The error**

`conda activate fenics`, `spyder`, `from dolfin import *`: **`No module named 'dolfin'`**.

**What works**

- `conda activate fenics`, `python`, `from dolfin import *`: worked in the first place.
- `conda activate fenics`, `ipython`, `from dolfin import *`: worked after some tweaking.
- `conda activate fenics`, `spyder`, `from dolfin import *`: worked after some tweaking.

**What I've done so far**

I installed `anaconda` using the suggested download from conda.

Running `conda create -n fenics -c conda-forge fenics`, `conda install fenics` and `conda activate fenics` to install and activate the fenics environment.

Then starting `python` and executing `from dolfin import *` works. `:)`

Running the same command in `ipython` doesn't work. Using `conda list` I found out that

```
    ...
    hdf5
    hypre
    icu
    isl
    jedi
    ...
```

there is no `ipython` in the list and `which` with `python` and `ipthon` yields

```
    /home/hannes/anaconda3/envs/fenics/bin/python
    /home/hannes/anaconda3/bin/python
```

Thus, `conda install ipython`, `ipython` and `from dolfin import *` works as well! `:)`

Running `spyder` and `from dolfin import *` throws the same error as with `ipython` before: `No module named 'dolfin'`. Maybe `spyder` isn't available in fenics' environment as well? `conda list` ... nope, not there. Now begins the fun part ... `:(`. `conda install spyder` and `which spyder` yields

```
    /home/hannes/anaconda3/envs/fenics/bin/spyder
```

However, running `spyder` throws the error

```
    libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so
    libGL error: driver pointer missing
    libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
    libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so
    libGL error: driver pointer missing
    libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
    libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
    libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
    Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

That seems to be some opengl issues. The solution from [github issue 6968](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/6968), `conda install pyopengl`, didn't help `:(`; still the same `libGL` errors. Therefore, `conda uninstall spyder`, `spyder` at least gave me back spyder.

**My best clue so far**

I tried adding the module to PYTHONPATH by adding

```
    export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/home/hannes/anaconda3/envs/fenics/lib/python3.6/site-packages/"
```

to `.bashrc` and running a Spyder that is not inside the fenics environment. No success, although I am not sure whether I did this step correctly. Why, `conda activate fenics`, `spyder` and `sys.path` spits out:

```
    /home/hannes/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder
    /home/hannes/anaconda3/lib/python36.zip
    /home/hannes/anaconda3/lib/python3.6
    /home/hannes/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload
    /home/hannes/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
    /home/hannes/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
    /home/hannes/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/extensions
    /home/hannes/.ipython
```

Since that didn't work I got `from dolfin import *` working after running `conda activate fenics`, `ipython`

```
    import sys
    sys.path.append('/home/hannes/anaconda3/envs/fenics/lib/python3.6/site-packages')
```

Since this is only a temporarily workaround (I have to add it every time I start Spyder) I am interested in a permanent fix.

I'd appreciate any help :).

Hannes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Since Spyder **3.3.1** (to be released in a couple of days), the solution is the following:

1. Activate your environment
2. Install the `spyder-kernels` package there, with the following command:

   `conda install spyder-kernels=0.*`
3. Also run there (in a system terminal)

   `python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"`

   and copy the path returned by that command.
4. Deactivate your environment and start Spyder from your root or base one.
5. Go to

   `Tools > Preferences > Python Interpreter > Use the following interpreter`

   and paste there the path you got in step 3.
6. Start a new IPython console and run

   `from dolfin import *`

   It should work now.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. When will "in a couple of days" be?^^ Is there some way I can keep track of the upcoming update?

Comment: It should be available on July 26 or 27. Spyder informs automatically of such updates to its users, unless you deactivated that mechanism in the past. If you did it, you can reactivate it by going to `Tools > Preferences > General > Advanced Settings` and selecting the option called `Check for updates on startup`.

Comment: Yes, it finally worked :). Thank you so much for your help :).